# How to use google tag manager and google ads in React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, google-tag-manager

I'm using [react-gtm](https://github.com/alinemorelli/react-gtm)
I would like to track user across the page and avoid rogue referral problem.
When a user clicks in google on an ad, she should land here:
https://mypage.com/?gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=GclidValue
So what I do is I take gclid from params, save it to cookies and send it to datalayer on everypage change.
Problem is when you copy that link to an url it works, but when you click on an ad in Google it doesn't.

```html
const Router = ({ children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const query = useQuery();
  const gclidCookie = getCookie('gclid');
  let gclidParam;

  if (gclidCookie) {
    gclidParam = gclidCookie;
  } else {
    setCookie('gclid', query.get('gclid'));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      'route has been changed',
      window.location.pathname + window.location.search + (gclidParam || ''),
    );
    TagManager.dataLayer({
      page: window.location.pathname + window.location.search,
      gclid: gclidParam || '',
    });
  }, [location.pathname]);
  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils} locale={pl}>
      <GlobalComponents>{children}</GlobalComponents>
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, gclid is not the only parameter adjusting the source. on-the-fly change of the source will lead to session breakage. Iterating through all the possible attribution/session changing parameters and keeping track of them manually is not a solution.

For SPAs, I would suggest declaring the tracker name. That's exactly how I solve it for React-based and other SPAs. It adds a tiny bit of trickiness to the tagging process, but from my point of view, it just adds a bit of discipline to the process, so I embrace it since discipline in GTM implementation is a rare sighting.

In short, tracker is GA's object that keeps this tracking context. that includes things like the original referrer, tracking settings, custom dimension, user id and a lot of things like that. You can get it in an array with ga.getAll(). You can try it here, on stack overflow:

[image]

So how GTM approaches it, is it defines a new tracker for each tag by default. Creating a new tracker make it so that subsequent tags would not inherit fields from the previously fired. Anyway, you can read about it more in Simo's and David's articles here: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/fix-rogue-referral-problem-single-page-sites/ and https://www.thyngster.com/tips-to-track-an-ajax-based-website-using-gtm-and-universal-analytics/

By creating an explicit tracker (setting the same name for each tag) I just override that behavior. The way I do it is via GTM settings variable that I then reference in every GA tag I create, to make it apply all the settings in the cfg var.

I know, Simo doesn't like the tracker declaration solution and offers more complex fixes as a replacement. I just go with the tracker and keep my GTM logic very structured and explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but to keep gclid in url is a business requirement, they are using it for google ads and they are not willing to use gtm for that. From what I've gathered is that it doesn't matter if gclid is one of the parameters. There shouldn't be a scenario that in the url there is a gclid and utm_source for example.

Comment: if you start forcing gclid to url, you will start noticing all kinds of issues. Like if a user came to the site from paid channel, getting gclid in their url. Then they realized they couldn't find what they were looking for, so they went to the older email to click on that link. And now they come to the site again, within 20 seconds, with utm params and with no gclid. And you're adding gclid on top of that? I say, poor business requirements deserve bugs like these.